# Unable to delete first row of database

Tags: php

I have a page to view and delete data from database. The delete is a link that clicked and pass the variable in url to another page for delete query. For example i have 3 rows in total in my database, i have no problem in deleting the last two rows but i was unable to delete the first row because the delete is deleting the record based on the "description" column, not the "ID" column. Below is the submission page and delete query page

viewreportdb.php

```
<!doctype html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Report Database </title>
    <link href="style/fg_membersite.css" rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
</head>
<?php

include('config.php');
include('adminconfig.php');

$sql = "SELECT * FROM report ORDER BY ID"; 
$result = mysql_query($sql);  
?>

<body>
    <form method="POST" action="reportsave.php" onSubmit="return validate(this);">
        <table id='fcolor2' class="viewdb3">
            <tr>
                <td style='border:2px solid black; background-color:#FF9933;' align=center> ID </td>
                <td style='border:2px solid black; background-color:#FF9933;' align=center> Name </td>
                <td style='border:2px solid black; background-color:#FF9933; width:auto;' align=center> Department </td>
                <td style='border:2px solid black; background-color:#FF9933; width:auto;' align=center> Description </td>
                <td style='border:2px solid black; background-color:#FF9933; width:auto;' align=center> Date </td>
            </tr><?!-- missing close tr -->
            <?php
            while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
            {
                ?>
                <tr>
                    <td style='border:2px solid black; background-color:#33FF00; width:auto' align=center><?php echo $row['ID'] ?></td>
                    <td style='border:2px solid black; background-color:#33FF00; width:auto' align=center><?php echo $row['name'] ?></td>
                    <td style='border:2px solid black; background-color:#33FF00; width:auto' align=center><?php echo $row['department'] ?></td>
                    <td><textarea rows="5" cols="50" name="description[]"><?php echo $row['description']; ?></textarea></td>
                    <td style='border:2px solid black; background-color:#33FF00; width:auto' align=center><?php echo $row['date'] ?></td>
                </tr><!-- missing close tr -->
                <tr>
                    <td><input class='edit' type = 'text' name="ID[]" value='<?php echo $row['ID'] ?>' maxlength="50"/></td>
                    <td><input class='edit' type = 'text' name="name[]" value='<?php echo $row['name'] ?>' maxlength="50"></td>
                    <td><input class='edit' type = 'text' name="department[]" value='<?php echo $row['department'] ?>' maxlength="50"></td>
                    <td>&nbsp;</td>
                    <td><input class='edit' type = 'text' name="date[]" value='<?php echo $row['date'] ?>' maxlength="50"></td>
                    <?php echo "<td><a href='http://localhost/kinhock/deletereport.php?description=".$row['description']."'>Delete</a></td>";?>
                </tr><!-- missing close tr -->
                <?php
            } ?>
            <tr class='btn2'><td><input type='submit' name='submit' value='Submit' /></td></tr>
            <tr class='btn2'><td><a href="http://localhost/kinhock/adminitem.php"> Back to Description </a></td></tr><!-- missing open & close tr-->
            <tr class='btn2'><td>&nbsp;<a href="http://localhost/kinhock/adminlogin.php">Logout</a></td></tr>
        </table>
    </form>
<?php
$ID=$row['ID'];
$name=$row['name'];
$department=$row['department'];
$date=$row['date'];
$description=$row['description'];
?>
</body>
</html>
```

deletereport.php

```
<?php
include('adminconfig.php');
include('config.php');

$description = $_GET['description'];

$sql="DELETE FROM `report` WHERE `description`='$description'";
$result=mysql_query($sql);

if(!$result){
    die('invalid query:'.mysql_error());
}else
    ?>
        <p style="font-family:arial;color:#0066CC;font-size:30px;">One row deleted...</p>
    <?php
header('Refresh:3; url=viewreportdb.php');
die;
?>
```

Comment: Can you please provide the MySQL error message? Maybe you should mysql_real_escape the $description.

Comment: you should really be using an unique ID to delete the entry, not description (I'm assuming description isn't even unique).

Comment: FYI: you are using deprecated mysql_* functions, and your code is prone to SQL injection

Comment: And yes, Prisoner is right, the best way to delete/update an entry is to identify it by a primary key (unique ID)

Comment: I wish i could delete by ID too, but how if a same ID report twice with different description, then the delete will delete two description together, which i do not wish to

Comment: You can't have two reports with the same `unique` ID - if you have multiple rows with the same ID, you haven't implemented the ID column correctly

Comment: and can i know how to prevent sql injection? i tried using other mysql_ function but it will cause the whole code not working

Comment: there is no function name `mysql_function`. @Nicky De Maeyer, means `mysql_query()`, and other function start with 'mysql_'

Answer (score 0):

Do not delete using `description` field because urlencoding and many more factors can break this code, even duplicate descriptions are quite possible, isn't it? Also your code is
liable to easiest [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) methods!

Change your code here:

```
<?php echo "<td><a href='http://localhost/kinhock/
deletereport.php?id=".$row['ID']."'>Delete</a></td>";?>
```

And your SQL query:

```
$id = intval($_GET['id']);
$sql="DELETE FROM `report` WHERE `id`='$id'";
```

Answer (score 0):

**STEP 1**

Send the ID,not the description,  for deletion.

```
<?php echo "<td><a href='http://localhost/kinhock    
/deletereport.php?id=".$row['ID']."'>Delete</a></td>";?>
```

**STEP 2**

Delete using the ID, not the description.

```
$id = intval($_GET['id']);
$sql="DELETE FROM `report` WHERE `id`=$id";
```

Comment: Is the passed id supposed to be an integer value? whats the id in url?

Comment: oh sorry, i forgot to mention to u tat the id is not integer, the data looks like ad001

Answer (score 0):

You should probably use the ID instead of the description within your where clause and in this line:

(change)

```
<?php echo "<td><a href='http://localhost/kinhock    
/deletereport.php?description=".$row['description']."'>Delete</a></td>";?>
```

(to)

```
<?php echo "<td><a href='http://localhost/kinhock    
/deletereport.php?id=".$row['ID']."'>Delete</a></td>";?>
```

and finally change:

```
$description = $_GET['description'];
$sql="DELETE FROM `report` WHERE `description`='$description'";
```

to:

```
$id = $_GET['id'];
$sql="DELETE FROM `report` WHERE `ID`='$id'";
```

Using the ID will be faster and more accurate assuming it is a primary or unique ID.

You may also want to use:

```
$id =  mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['id']);
```

to prevent SQL injection.

Answer (score 0):

I believe your report table's ids are based on the users IDs right? Why don't you make it such that each report had an ID(report ID), User_ID(eg. admin001) and a description. In this way if admin001 makes report A it will have ID 1, if admin001 makes report B it will have ID 2. si when you want to delete Report A you use

```
$sql = "delete from {tablename} where ID={report ID}";
```

Comment: hm, this sound like a good idea, will try to work it out then